# formData cannot arrive to backend

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a team section, that it is a dynamic form. You can insert team members as much as you want, and it includes, `"memberName", "memberDescription", "memberJobTitle", "images"`.

Really do not understand why but something is wrong in the frontend, somehow file does not arrive to backend, when I submit to create a team member, I got this message:

> message: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')

However,

1. When I try upload file to team member on Postman with form-data, it works. So, I assume problem is not in the backend.

   team[0][memberName]: "Lala"
   team[0][memberJobTitle]: "Lala"
   team[0][images][0]: "image.jpg"
   team[0][memberDescription]: "Lala"
2. In the frontend, I can see the file that I uploaded when I submit in `console.log(values)`.

   team: Array(1)
   0:
   images:Array(1)
   0: FileList {0: File, length: 1}
   length: 1
   [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
   memberDescription: "work with us 5 years long"
   memberJobTitle: "marketing"
   memberName: "Jane Doe"
3. If I log `console.log("append image: ", item.images[0]);` it also shows me a FileList.

   FileList {0: File, length: 1}
   0: File {name: 'real-estate-logo-template_1195-19.jpg.webp', lastModified: 1672667306966, lastModifiedDate: Mon Jan 02 2023 13:48:26 GMT+0000 (Western European Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 9894, …}
   length: 1

submitHandler

```
const submitHandler = async (values) => {
    const formData = new FormData();

    // append other fields

    values.team = values.team || [{}];

    values.team.forEach((item, index) => {
      formData.append(`team[${index}][memberName]`, item.memberName || "");
      //append other team fields

      formData.append(`team[${index}][images][0]`, item.images[0]);

      console.log("append image: ", item.images[0]);
    });


    await axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: `http://localhost:8080/api/pages/${pageId}/aditional-section`,
      data: formData,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
      },
    })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });

    console.log(values);
  };
```

I'm using Formik to handle form.

```
     <FieldArray name="team">
    {({ insert, remove, push }) => (
      <div>
        {values.team.length > 0 &&
          values.team.map((item, index) => (
            <div className="row" key={index}>
              <div className="col">
                <label htmlFor={`team.${index}.images[0]`}>
                  Upload image
                </label>

                {/* <Field
                  name={`team.${index}.images`}
                  type="file"
                /> */}

                <FileInput
                  name={`team.${index}.images[0]`}
                  type="file"
                  value={undefined}
                />

                <ErrorMessage
                  name={`team.${index}.images[0]`}
                  component="div"
                  className="field-error"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        <button
          type="button"
          className="secondary"
          onClick={() =>
            push({
              memberName: "",
              memberJobTitle: "",
              memberDescription: "",
              images: "",
            })
          }
        >
          Add Member
        </button>
      </div>
    )}
</FieldArray>
```

Comment: Line number you are getting the error?

Comment: There is no line number, it trigger when I submit, because does not arrive to backend. 

`xhr.js:247          POST http://localhost:8080/api/pages/63b23c83d3696eecffffe1e5/aditional-section 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: Remove the content-type header. Why did you set it?

Comment: Because automatically it's application/json, but I'm sending files via upload, so it should be form-data to handle both situations

Answer (score 2):

[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append#parameters) states:

> value
>
> The field's value. This can be a string or Blob (including subclasses such as File). If none of these are specified the value is converted to a string.

It appears that the `FileList` type *isn't* supported but the `File` type **is**. Try looping through the `FileList` and appending each file to the `formData` like so.

```
const submitHandler = async (values) => {
    ...

    values.team.forEach((item, index) => {
      formData.append(`team[${index}][memberName]`, item.memberName || "");
      //append other team fields
      // Before
      // formData.append(`team[${index}][images][0]`, item.images[0]);
      
      // After - Loop through images, and append the File
      for (let i = 0; i < item.images[0].length; i++) {
         const file = item.images[0].files[i];
         formData.append(`team[${index}][images][0]`, file);
      }

      console.log("append image: ", item.images[0]);
    });


    ...
  };
```

---

This should work, granted your backend is set up to receive multiple files.

Comment: I'd probably increment the `images` index so OP can upload multiple files... `formData.append(\`team[${index}][images][${i}]\`, file)`

Comment: If he calls `formData.getAll(\`team[${index}][images][0]\`)` on his backend, an array of each file would be returned. You can have multiple formData key/value pairs that share the same key. It does look like he was going the direction of having a new key for each image, though, so good point.

Comment: Sure, but then why bother with index numbers at all :D

Comment: If there are multiple teams, using indices in the keys would help differentiate their data, if i'm not mistaken :p

Comment: I meant on the images. It wouldn't be as important there and I'd probably just omit the indexes, provided the backend can handle that properly

Comment: I see... I avoided changing `\`team[${index}][images][0]\`` for brevity. But I agree... I'd probably omit the indices as well `\`team[${index}][images]\`` is a little easier on the eyes

Comment: I managed to handle like this:    `formData.append(´team[${index}][images][0]´, item.images[0][0]);`. Since `item.images[0]`is a `FileList`, does not have any path. So that's why I was having that error message. In this way, it will append to first file in array to de `FormData` object.